# Roll until 5 or 6 is obtained on die without mid-game cash out

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

This question is from QuantGuide(Busted 6 II):
Suppose you play a game where you continually roll a die until you obtain either a 5 or a
6. If you receive a
5, then you cash out the sum of all of your previous rolls (excluding the
5). If you receive a
6, then you receive no payout. You do not have the decision to cash out mid-game. What is your expected payout?
My Approach:
In the case when we can't cash out mid-game the expected value will be 2.5.
Now in the case of stopping midgame, we calculate the expected value at each stage of the throw.
For the $i^{th}$ throw the expected value will be:
\begin{equation}
\frac{2}{3}^i(2.5i)+\frac{2}{3}^{i-1}(2.5(i-1))\frac{1}{6}
\end{equation}
The 2.5 value is due to at each throw the average value of the dice roll will be $\frac{1+2+3+4}{4}$. The value I am getting is 2.59 but it doesn't pass. It would be great to get some help.

Comment: What is the first term, $\left ( \dfrac{2}{3} \right)^i \cdot 2.5i$, for?

Comment: The same question about the second term.

Comment: Since you can cash out anywhere, this problem needs to be solved by first determining the optimal strategy. What is your strategy in your approach?

Comment: @Haris There is a 4/6 probability of getting a number from 1 to 4, and since average of these 4 numbers is 2.5, the OP implies that expected value of consecutive i rolls where each roll is between 1 and 4 is $(\frac23)^i \cdot 2.5i$

Comment: @DevanshAgarwal Please read the question again. You cannot cash out mid-game. Also, you can read my answer as to why I think only the second term is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The game ends if you roll a $5$ or $6$, with probability $\frac13$. The expected number of trials until a trial with probability $\frac13$ succeeds is $3$. So you expect to roll $3$ times, $2$ of which count towards the payout, each of which has an average of $2.5$. The probability that you actually get that payout is $\frac12$. So the expected payout is $2\cdot2.5\cdot\frac12=2.5$.

Comment: Please Check the edit

Comment: @MdKaifFaiyaz: I reverted that edit. That’s not how this site works. Questions aren’t the original poster’s private property; they’re for everyone to benefit from. You’d asked a question, and four people put effort into answering it, some of them correctly. If you then find that you asked a different question than you’d intended to ask, the proper way to deal with that is to ask a new question, not to invalidate all the work already invested in the original question. If you ask a new question, feel free to ping me here and I’ll take a look at it.

Comment: Hi, @joriki I've posted a new question.Please have a lookhttps://math.stackexchange.com/q/4887164/932398

Comment: @MdKaifFaiyaz: Funny, you wrote that precisely as I was checking here to see whether you’d responded. I’ll take a look...

Answer (score 1):

Like I asked in the comments, I don't know why you have the first term,  $\left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^i \cdot 2.5^i$, in your expression.

For the player to win anything, there must be at least two rolls and the game should end with a $5$. If the game ends at $i +1$ rolls, the payout would be $2.5i$. The probability that the game ends with a $5$ at $(i+1)$th roll is $\left( \frac{4}{6} \right)^i \cdot \frac{1}{6}$.

So, the  expected payout is

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{4}{6} \right)^i \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot 2.5i \; = \; \frac{5}{12} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{4}{6} \right)^i \cdot i$$

I don't know how to get the sum but the answer would be $2.5$.

I believe there could be a simpler solution but it doesn't strike me at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore for a second that there's only a $\frac12$ chance of getting the payout. Then consider the first roll. There's a $\frac13$ chance of getting 5 or 6, so you end with $0$ and a $\frac23$ chance of getting any other roll, which puts you back in the same position except with on average $\frac52$ added to your final score. So for this 'game' we have
$$\mathbb{E}S=\frac13\cdot0+\frac23(\frac52+\mathbb{E}S)$$
Which tells us
$$\frac13\mathbb{E}S=\frac53$$
so $\mathbb{E}S=5$. The answer for your game will just be half of this.

Comment: Please Check edit

Answer (score -1):

A faster method would be assuming 6 is also cashing out, then dividing by 2 (because 6 and 5 are identical other than the fact that 6 multiplies your score by 0). you have a 1/3 chance of cashing out each turn, meaning each outcome is expected to be rolled "half a time". the calculation $\frac{\frac{1+2+3+4}{2}}{2} =2.5$ is still correct, just this is an easier method.

One thing I don't understand. Where did you get 2.59?

Comment: Please check edits

Comment: what edits did you add?