# QuantGuide Busted 6 II

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

This question is from QuantGuide(Busted 6 II):
Suppose you play a game where you continually roll a die until you obtain either a 5 or a
6. If you receive a
5, then you cash out the sum of all of your previous rolls (excluding the
5). If you receive a
6, then you receive no payout. You have the decision to cash out mid-game. What is your expected payout following the optimal strategy?
My Approach:
First I look into the case when we can't cash out mid-game. The expected value is 2.5 in this case.
Now for the additional option of stopping midgame, we calculate the expected value at each stage of the dice throw.
For the $i^{th}$ throw the expected value will be:
\begin{equation}
\frac{2}{3}^i(2.5i)+\frac{2}{3}^{i-1}(2.5(i-1))\frac{1}{6}
\end{equation}
The 2.5 value is due to each throw having the average value of the dice roll to be $\frac{1+2+3+4}{4}$(the first term is for when all the throws till now don't have 5 or 6 and the second term is for the case of landing with a 5 in the $i^{th}$ throw). The value I am getting is approximately 2.59.

---

The case without the option to cash out was solved at [Roll until 5 or 6 is obtained on die without mid-game cash out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4886525).

Comment: For this version, you'll need to consider the optimal exit threshold.  That is,  the value of built up earnings you need before it's better to quit than roll again.  Once you have that threshold, you can work backwards to get the expected value from any starting level (including $0$).  Absent knowledge of that value, you can work numerically, trying different thresholds until you maximize the initial value of the game.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal strategy clearly takes the form of playing until you’ve obtained some threshold value and then cashing out, so we need to determine the threshold. At the last value under the threshold, you know you’re going to cash out if you don’t roll a $5$ or $6$. So the threshold is determined by the condition that a single roll will decrease the expected payout.

If your current sum is $s$, the expected payout if you cash out after the next roll is

$$
\frac16\cdot0+\frac16\cdot s+\frac46\cdot\left(s+\frac{1+4}2\right)\;.
$$

This is equal to $s$ for $s=10$. So if you have a sum of $10$, it doesn’t matter whether you roll once more or not, if you have less you should continue, and if you have more you should cash out.

The additional payout $a_s$ you expect to gain when you have a sum of $s$ is

\begin{eqnarray*}
a_s
&=&
\frac16\cdot(-s)+\frac16\cdot0+\frac16\sum_{k=1}^4(k+a_{s+k})
\\
&=&
\frac{10-s+\sum_{k=1}^4a_{s+k}}6\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

with the “final values” $a_k=0$ for $k\ge10$. A linear *ansatz* yields the particular solution $a_s=\frac{5-s}2$, and writing $a_s=b_s+\frac{5-s}2$ leads to the homogeneous recurrence

$$
b_s=\frac16\sum_{k=1}^4b_{s+k}\;,
$$

now with the “final values” $b_{10}=\frac52$, $b_{11}=3$, $b_{12}=\frac72$, $b_{13}=4$. As this is a fourth-order linear recurrence, it can be solved analytically, but [the solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%28k%29%20%3D%20%28a_%28k%2B1%29%2Ba_%28k%2B2%29%20%2B%20a_%28k%2B3%29%20%20%2B%20a_%28k%2B4%29%29%2F6) isn’t very helpful. Here’s a table with the results of working backwards from the threshold:

\begin{array}{c|c}
s&b_s\\\hline
13&4\\
12&\frac72\\
11&3\\
10&\frac52\\
9&\frac{13}{6}\\
8&\frac{67}{36}\\
7&\frac{343}{216}\\
6&\frac{1753}{1296}\\
5&\frac{9031}{7776}\\
4&\frac{46369}{46656}\\
3&\frac{237751}{279936}\\
2&\frac{1219729}{1679616}\\
1&\frac{6266215}{10077696}\\
0&\frac{32159329}{60466176}\\
\end{array}

Thus, the value you gain from the option to cash out is

$$b_0=\frac{32159329}{60466176}\approx0.5318565\;,$$

and the total value of the game with the option is

$$
a_0=\frac52+b_0=\frac{183324769}{60466176}\approx3.0318565\;.
$$

[Here’s the code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question4887164Computation.java) I used to solve the recurrence, and [here’s the code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question4887164Simulation.java) I used to simulate the experiment to check the results. There you can also change the threshold to check that $10$ is indeed optimal.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to check yesterday.Then what should be the answer? Like the expected value in this case

Comment: The answer 10 is not working

Comment: @MdKaifFaiyaz: No, it wouldn’t work, since it’s the optimal stopping threshold, not the expected payout that the question asked for. The expected payout is $a_0=\frac{183324769}{60466176}$.

Comment: but this answer also fails. This is the link to the question https://www.quantguide.io/questions/busted-6-ii

Comment: @MdKaifFaiyaz: Well, I guess they got it wrong ;-). If it was just the analytical answer, I’d say it’s quite possible that I made a mistake, but it’s unlikely that I got the same wrong answer analytically and by simulation – unless, of course, I misunderstood the question. But the question seems quite unambiguous, I don’t know which part of it I could have misinterpreted. Since my solution would be quite tedious to calculate in an interview, it seems that they have something else in mind that requires less number crunching. They may well just be mistaken.

Comment: @MdKaifFaiyaz: By the way, there’s a purported solution [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/18vug9x/expected_payout_for_dice_game/), but it doesn’t make sense to me, and the value is also not accepted as the answer by QuantGuide.

Comment: @MdKaifFaiyaz: I sent them feedback, linking to this solution. Let’s see whether they respond. You could also try to find someone with a premium account who has access to the solutions.